# Why do video streaming services buffer when I plug in my headphones?

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, audio-streaming, netflix, digital-audio

I've noticed while using Netflix, Xbox Video, and Amazon, when I plug in my headphones the video will buffer as if the audio output change affects the streaming services.

Can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the player switches to a different audio stream when headphones are connected. For example, if you are watching Netflix on a tablet, it may stream only Mono audio in order to conserve bandwidth (which is all that is necessary on a tablet with one speaker) and then switch to Stereo when headphones are connected.

Comment: I don't have proof, but I agree with this. I have an HDMI splitter and when a new display comes online while video is playing the same thing happans, they explain that the audio and video must be adjusted to play on the least capable device.