# Why does plugging headphones in cause Netflix to re-buffer the video feed completely?

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, netflix

I noticed that any time I'm watching Netflix (iOS, Windows8, OSX), and I plug in headphones, the video feed stops and buffers all the way from 0%. **Why?**

Comment: Possibly a better fit for webapps site

Comment: @BrianAdkins Seems to me like the tags `netflix` and `audio streaming` mean it's on-topic.

Comment: I don't think it's off-topic... I think it's on-topic for both sites.

Comment: [Why do video streaming services buffer when I plug in my headphones?](http://superuser.com/q/770740/423985)